# I'm unable to make multiple 2d objects bounce off a canvas x and y

Tags: javascript

I'm still getting used to objects, but no matter what I do I can't get my objects to reverse their x or y. It doesn't even register that any of them have hit a canvas wall, they just go off screen.
Here's my code:

```js
"use strict";
 //variables
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var randomX = 0; //in for loop use Math.random()
 var randomY = 0; //in for loop use Math.random()
 var ballRadius = 10;
 var ballX = canvas.width/2;
 var ballY = canvas.height-30;
 var ballMove = [];
 var ballObject = [];

    //declares the objects x and y's
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  ballObject[i] = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  ballMove[i] = { x:1, y:-1 };
  randomX = (Math.random() * (canvas.width-ballRadius)) +1;
  randomY = (Math.random() * (canvas.height-ballRadius)) +1;
  ballObject[i].x = randomX;
  ballObject[i].y = randomY;
 }


 function draw()
 {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        //didn't actually need this for loop but was experimenting
  for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
   drawBall(i);
  }
   moveBall();
        //this method should check the x and y of the balls.
   bounceBall();
 }
    // basic ball drawing function
 function drawBall(i)
 {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballObject[i].x, ballObject[i].y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
    //extremely basic move function (just adds to x and y)
 function moveBall()
 {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  ballObject[i].x += ballMove[i].x;
  ballObject[i].y += ballMove[i].y;
  }
   
 }
    //WHY IT NO WORK 
    //for whatever reason this function doesn't reverse the x and y
 function bounceBall()
 {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   if (ballObject[i].x == canvas.width-ballRadius || ballObject[i].x == 0+ballRadius){
    alert("i've hit a wall");
    ballMove[i].x = -ballMove[i].x;
   }
   if (ballObject[i].y == canvas.height-ballRadius || ballObject[i].y == 0+ballRadius){
    alert("i've hit a wall");
    ballMove[i].y = -ballMove[i].y;
   }
  }
 }

 setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
    <style>
     * { padding: 0; margin: 15; }
     canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

  <script src="ballPop.js">

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've kinda made a mess of my code trying to use objects and make them bounce.
I made a brick break game after following some tut online and the bounce worked fine - however that same concept doesn't seem to work with objects.

Comment: Unrelated but change your script src to be relative so you dont leak details like your name.  Use console.log instead of alert to not pause execution and put some in to track your x/y values as the ball moves. This may show you your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my src - completely forgot I had that in there. Also, I was trying to use alert to see if it was hitting the wall but not switching the x and y. I'll try tracking the x and y to see what happens - update in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely has to do with the fact that your ball coordinates are floating point values.  For example:

```
> (Math.random() * (200 - 3)) + 1
179.1025927176495
```

When you do your checks in `bounceBall` you may get better results by checking if the ball would exceed the boundary

```
function bounceBall()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (ballObject[i].x >= canvas.width-ballRadius || ballObject[i].x <= 0+ballRadius) {
            alert("i've hit a wall");
            ballMove[i].x = -ballMove[i].x;
        }
        if (ballObject[i].y >= canvas.height-ballRadius || ballObject[i].y <= 0+ballRadius){
            alert("i've hit a wall");
            ballMove[i].y = -ballMove[i].y;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** == changed to >= and <=

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it's floating! I could probably use something like Math.floor(Math.random()); right? That's a great idea. I'm almost 100% sure that's it! will check back in a sec.

Comment: That was it! After flooring the randoms and using the <= or >= the balls stay within their boundries!

Comment: It's a good idea to use the inequality comparison because as you get into more complex code, you will generally have floating point coordinates.

For example your setInterval of 10 may not actually run every 10ms depending how slow or bogged down the computer is.  In more advanced animation / game loops you will generally have a speed as units/second and on each iteration see actual elapsed time since the last update, and change the position by timeElapsed * speedOfObject.